# $\log_3 0.095$, solve without calculator but with log table or $4$ figure table

Tags: logarithms

Well I've tried equating to $x$ i.e. $$3^x  =0.095,$$

then taking both side to $\log_{10}$, so we have 
$$\log_{10}3^x =\log_{10}0.095$$, then I crossed $x$ to the other side ,i.e., $$x\log_{10}3=\log_{10}0.095.$$

Then I divided both sides by $\log_{10}3$.

Meaning that $$x =\frac{\log_{10} 0.095}{ \log_{10}3}$$

Then i solved on but didn't get the answer and I was confused, our head of study group says the answer is $-2.14$. Guys help , pls its not a homework

Comment: this is very hard to read.  What's the base of the $\log$?  Is this meant to be $\log_b 3^{.095}$ for some base $b$?  Don't see how that could be negative though...

Comment: I agree with @lulu. Please in the title place parentheses wherever you can.

Comment: Just to be precise...it looks like you want to compute $\log_b x$, but it's hard to sort out what $b$ and $x$ are.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I tried to recover the message. Did I edit your question correctly?

Comment: What are the results on the table for each?

Answer (score 1):

$$x=\frac{\log_{10}0.095}{\log_{10} 3} \approx -2.14$$

Perhaps you have trouble reading the table?

Just a simple check: $$log_{10}(0.095) \approx -1.022$$

Do you get that?

Comment: Yeah you edited it right. Pls i meant solving without a calculator and pls break log 10^0.095 down may explain further

Comment: Do you have the table that you are using online? Just want to make sure we are looking at the same table.

Comment: http://myhandbook.info/table_commonlog.html Suppose you are using this table. you can find the value of $\log_{10}(9.5)$ there. So use the trick $\log_{10} (0.095)=\log_{10} (9.5 \times 10^{-2})=-2+\log_{10}(9.5).$

Comment: p/s: typing tips, include "dollar sign" around mathy stuff. for subscript use "_". Type log as "\log".